# Laravel - redirect to route with id after successfull ajax

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-routing

I am trying to figure this out. I have backend in laravel and i am returning id of new created client. How can i use this param in js redirect? This is my best try but i am getting into this url: **client/%27+response.id+%27** it should be **client/15**

```
$.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '{{ route('add-new-client') }}',
            data: {
                shop_name: shop_name
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $("#addClientModal").modal("hide");
                // Přesměrování na URL s předáním nového id
                window.location.href = '{{ route("client", ["id" => "' + response.id + '"]) }}';
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
```

Solution in PHP, after a while my patience run out and i come up with this idea, i just return whole url created in laravel. Works like a charm

```
public function xxx(Request $request)
    {
    .... code ....
    return response()->json([
        'url' => url(action([ClientController::class, 'index'], ['id' => $shop->id])),
        'success' => 'Shop byl úspěšně vytvořen.'
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything inside `{{ ... }}` is evaluated in php.

Hence nothing from JS land is available inside it (including the response) and thats why `id` for the route is being evaluated as a literal string.

You can test this in a url decoder where `%27+response.id+%27` becomes `'+response.id+'`

Your options are:

1. Send the redirect url as part of the response after creating the entity (as you are doing for a workaround). This is a good strategy as the FE can remain "dumb"
2. set the redirect url directly. This is a very common but slightly brittle approach
   `window.location.href = '/client/' + response.id`